# 「しかし, 良く引き受けたな？事情が事情だ、断って他の隊に話を回しちまっても良かったと思うぜ？」

Tags: syntax, set-phrases, parsing

I'm reading a passage from a fictional work, character A has been assigned with a task (publishing a controversial article) from his boss that he has mixed feelings about, one of his superiors (character B)  later notices the uncomfortable look on his face, they have a short conversation about a few things related to the conversation they had with the boss earlier. Character B then takes one of A's older published articles in hand from the tabletop, looks through it and says this;

> B「しかし,  良く引き受けたな？事情が事情だ、断って他の隊に話を回しちまっても良かったと思うぜ？」
>
> A responds 「……俺も、迷っちゃいるんすけどね」

However, this is where I've hit a snag; I'm not quite sure how one would parse this correctly.

I had a go at it with what I have learned so far and some guess work and came up with this:

> "however, you often accept this sort of thing? Circumstances are circumstances, I think it's good to reject passing the matter around to other units right?"
>
> "…but I also hesitated [when it came to making a decision(?)]."

Now this feels like a really shaky translation to me, it doesn't seem to make too much sense either so that is why I ask for help with how it should be parsed.

A lot of confusion stems from 断って I  almost feel like a particle should follow this the way I perceived the sentence, but to me a translation of this part would be more likely "to refuse and~" because of the te form, of course my attempt at a translation says otherwise so I'm confused.

The 話を回しちまって is also something I haven't come across yet, is it a set phrase? I think it probably means "sending the matter around to~" some clarification would be awesome.

Finally the ぜ？at the end, does this indicate a rise in intonation here in this particular context? So maybe one could translate it as "right?"

Answer (score 1):

> B「しかし, 良く引き受けたな？事情が事情だ、断って他の隊に話を回しちまっても良かったと思うぜ？」
>
> A responds 「……俺も、迷っちゃいるんすけどね」
>
> "however, you often accept this sort of thing? Circumstances are circumstances, I think it's good to reject passing the matter around to other units right?"
>
> "…but I also hesitated [when it came to making a decision(?)]."

---

> 断って I almost feel like a particle should follow this the way I perceived the sentence, but to me a translation of this part would be more likely "to refuse and~" because of the te form,

Your assumption of "***to refuse and ~***" is correct. I assume you are feeling it's illogical to talk about something that happens after refusing it, but it's just a typical word of an irresponsible remark; they know or expect that it's the logical consequence that someone has to do it if they refuse it.

話を回す, I don't know if this is a set phrase or not, but 回す can mean either pass around or pass something to someone. We also often say 仕事を回す, 上司がいい仕事を回してくれた, etc.

The ぜ？ in reality doesn't sound very much like a decent word at a work place, but it might be an effort not to offend, and probably that is why it has '？' So, I think ', right?' is a good translation.

Well, by the way, the 良く here means not *often* but something like *dare (to do something)*, an intensifier. The speaker is expressing surprise because he's accepted it.